# Set SelectedIndex of listbox appear at top of the screen

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have listbox bounded to a collection. I am using selectedIndex to change the selected index of listbox item, but this doesn't work for me to set the selected index at top of the screen. My listbox contains more than 100 items.

```
lsbReadingChapter.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToByte(App.Recent.AyaID);
lsbReadingChapter.ScrollIntoView(lsbReadingChapter.SelectedIndex);
```

I want the selected item should always appear at the top of the screen each time i select new item in the listbox, Would it be possible to do it in listbox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this it could help you:

```
lsbReadingChapter.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToByte(App.Recent.AyaID);
lsbReadingChapter.UpdateLayout();
lsbReadingChapter.ScrollIntoView(lsbReadingChapter.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: Thanks, This goes to the index, but it doesn't bring the selected item at the top.

Comment: ok... i think you have to apply your own logic for this because their is not any other method to this

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. you need to get selected item on selection change and insert that item in first index of your colllection(Listbox item source) and remove selected item from previous index after that again change ListBox itemSource to new Source.
Try this

```
//Create your listBox itemsource
List<chapter> lstChapter = new List<chapter> lstChapter();
lstChapter.Add(new chapter());
lstChapter.Add(new chapter());
lstChapter.Add(new chapter());
lstChapter.Add(new chapter());

//Assign itemSource to listBox
lsbReadingChapter.ItemSource = lstChapter ;

//Get selected Item of listBox
chapter selectedItem= lsbReadingChapter.SelectedItem.
//get index of selected item
int previousIndex = lstChapter.IndexOf(selectedItem);
//Remove item from that index
lstChapter=lstChapter.RemoveAt(previousIndex);
//insert selected item in first index
 lstChapter.Insert(0, selectedItem);
//Reassign your listbox itemSource
lsbReadingChapter.ItemSource = lstChapter ;
```

Comment: Thanks, previous index returns -1, Though its the same object. ArabicTextWithTranslation selectedItem = (ArabicTextWithTranslation)lsbReadingChapter.SelectedItem;
int previousIndex = ls.IndexOf(selectedItem); //it's -1

Comment: Oh, Sorry, You didnt understand my question. I don't want to re-organize items in listbox, I only want the selected index should always appear at top of the screen. The items order in list should never be changed.

Comment: @ARH  previous index returns -1 because you get previous index in listBox selectionChanged event. add this on top of all code.... if(lsbReadingChapter.SelectedIndex==-1) return;

Answer (score 0):

You could call `ScrollIntoView()` twice - e.g.:

```
lsbReadingChapter.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToByte(App.Recent.AyaID);
//First scroll to the bottom of the list
lsbReadingChapter.ScrollIntoView(lsbReadingChapter.Items[lsbReadingChapter.Items.Count - 1]);
lsbReadingChapter.UpdateLayout();
//Then scroll to the selected index
lsbReadingChapter.ScrollIntoView(lsbReadingChapter.SelectedItem);
lsbReadingChapter.UpdateLayout();
```

Comment: Sorry - you could try my updated code. It works on my Windows 7 laptop with WPF and .NET 4.0. If it still doesn't work maybe it's a Windows Phone issue.